# Hi, I am usuing a dell laptop with Ubuntu. I am unable to open any application

Tags: 14.04, dell

After couple of weeks, I started using my laptop. I am unable to open any application in the laptop. I can see two files on desktop. I can open them, I am trying to start programs using keyboard, still not working. I can see the desktop screen saver nothing else. could you please help?

Comment: Please provide OS/release details, you've tagged an EOL/ESM release, which is now off-topic on this site (unless your question is specific about needing help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on what applications would you like to open?
Have you tried to open them from the terminal?
Which flavor of Ubuntu are you using?

Please, mods, I can't comment because the system is asking me for a 50 reputation that I don't have.

Comment: Any application, I am trying to click windows button and trying to open, it is not working. All I can see on screen is, two files on desktop and screen saver. Nothing else

Comment: Well if the OS is unresponsibe, why don't you try moving to a different newer version of Ubuntu?
Or if your laptop it's old, then try switching to Lubuntu

Comment: Okay. is there any article which helps me to move to newer version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, use https://www.linode.com/docs/security/upgrading/upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04/
Again, if the laptop it's old, I'd rather recommend switching to Lubuntu instead, it's an official flavor of Ubuntu, designed to run on slow, less capable machines, visit the official site here at: https://lubuntu.net/